# When (and/or where) is it okay to ask questions about homemaking processes?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

#### Is there a clear guideline about what makes a homemaking question appropriate for this site?

I'm interested in process improvements, however, there seems to be some inconsistency about whether [homemaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homemaking) questions are [on topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/how-can-i-get-rid-of-a-mouse-in-my-house) or [not](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/why-is-there-white-crust-on-my-dishes-after-they-are-washed-in-the-dish-washer).

#### Are there a better SE sites for home-making questions?

While it's clear that all general cooking questions belong at [SE cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), it seems obvious that it would be more appropriate to ask questions about stove repair on here.  Further, questions about how to adapt a stove for use as a convection oven seem to blur the line.

<sub>**Moderators**: please note and help resolve the duplicate tags I found</sub>

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "home making"? I think I know, but I could well be wide of the mark.

Comment: @ChrisF I've clarified my quesiton a bit more, and added a link to the wikipedia definition for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using the linked [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homemaking) as a guide:

## Household tools

Potentially on topic, when asking about the use and maintenance of said tools.

## Cooking

Off topic.  See [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).

## Housekeeping

Off topic.

### Laundry

Off topic, unless asking about the maintenance, repair, or installation of washers and dryers.

## Maintenance

On topic.

### Home Maintenance

On topic.

### Lawn Maintenance.

Off topic. See [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

## Management

Off topic.

### De-cluttering

Off topic, unless asking about building shelves or other storage furniture.

### Household Purchasing

Off topic.

### Servants

Off topic.

## Work Strategies

Off topic.

## Gender Deviance

Off topic.

Comment: so where does sub optimal operation of an appliance (a type of tool) fall?  Especially if the under performance is within the manufacturer's spec?  ie: washing machine not getting clothes clean, stove burner not lighting?  It's not repair, but might be modification and thus fall under maintenance? or work strategist?

Comment: Decluttering is on-topic at [productivity.se]; money management at [money.se].